# How to add column and records on a dataset given a condition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a program that brands data as OutOfRange based on the values present on certain columns.

I have three columns: `Age`, `Height`, and `Weight`. I want to create a fourth column called `OutOfRange` and assign it a value of 0(false) or 1(true) if the values in those three columns exceed a specific threshold.

If age is lower than 18 or higher than 60, that row will be assigned a value of 1 (0 otherwise). If height is lower than 5, that row will be assigned a value of 1 (0 otherwise), and so on.

Is it possible to create a column and then add/overwrite values to that column? It would be awesome if I can do that with Spark. I know SQL so if there is anything I can do with the `dataset.SQL()` function please let me know.

Comment: what If `18<age<60` and `height<5`? wouldn't that conflict?

Comment: Nope. It would still be considered wrong. If ANY of those conditions fail, the final result should be 1(true). I know Spark implements the `AND` and `OR` statements on its columns, and in my case I will be suing the `OR` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a dataframe as

```
+---+------+------+
|Age|Height|Weight|
+---+------+------+
|20 |3     |70    |
|17 |6     |80    |
|30 |5     |60    |
|61 |7     |90    |
+---+------+------+
```

You can apply `when` function to apply the logics explained in the question as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("OutOfRange", when(col("Age") <18 || col("Age") > 60 || col("Height") < 5, 1).otherwise(0))
```

which would result following dataframe

```
+---+------+------+----------+
|Age|Height|Weight|OutOfRange|
+---+------+------+----------+
|20 |3     |70    |1         |
|17 |6     |80    |1         |
|30 |5     |60    |0         |
|61 |7     |90    |1         |
+---+------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Awesome! That's perfect. However, I just have one question. In the case that I have already defined the `OutOfRange` column and assigned 0 to all the values, and I just want to change the 0 to 1 where the condition mentioned above evaluates to true. Will your function still work or will I have to do something different?

Comment: Yes it should work :) withColumn will update the values in a column if that column is present or creates a new column if the column is not present in the original dataframe :)

Comment: I just tried it and I would like to say it works but it didn't do that second part. The program works but instead of updating the values, it overwrites the values. So if I have all zeros and decide to change to one those values where the condition evaluates to true (and not using the `otherwise` function), it correctly puts the one values but then it overwrites the zeros to null :(

Comment: I tried in mine and its just fine :). You might have missed something else. Can you add another question so that I or somebody else can help you :)

Comment: @GuillermoHerrera if you skip otherwise then the when function doesn't know what to be done if the condition fails. so it puts null. I hope you've already sorted that out.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a column and then add/overwrite values to that column? It would be awesome if I can do that with Spark. I know SQL so if there is anything I can do with the dataset.SQL() function please let me know.

This is not possible without recreating the Dataset all together since Datasets are inherently immutable.

However you can save the Dataset as a Hive table, which will allow you to do what you want to do. Saving the Dataset as a Hive table will write the contents of your Dataset to disk under the default spark-warehouse directory.

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("my_table")
// Add a row
spark.sql("insert into my_table (Age, Height, Weight, OutofRange) values (20, 30, 70, 1)
// Update a row
spark.sql("update my_table set OutOfRange = 1 where Age > 30")
....
```

Hive support must be enabled for spark at time of instantiation in order to do this.